# Prove or (dis)prove that : $f\left(x\right)+f\left(\phi\right)<0$

Tags: power-series, approximation, hyperbolic-functions, constants, error-function

Working on an approximation of the error function I found this (true?)inequality :

let $40/9\leq x\leq 90/4$ then it seems we have :

$$f\left(x\right)+f\left(\phi\right)<0$$

Where :

$$f\left(x\right)=\operatorname{erf}\left(x\right)-\tanh\left(x\right)+\frac{\left(-\tanh\left(\frac{x}{4}+\frac{1}{2x}\right)-\frac{x^{\phi}}{x^{e}+1}+1\right)}{2}$$

And $e$ is the euler constant and $\phi$ the golden ratio.

Using the expansion found on wikipedia for the error function or simply using a second derivative I can show for $x\geq 0$:

$$\operatorname{erf}(x)-\tanh(x)\geq 0$$

But we have a big problem around $x=40/9$ and the expansion becomes not praticable .

How to (dis)prove it ?

Comment: what is $\phi ?$

Comment: @WillJagy The golden ratio .

Comment: To be more precise : $\frac{631}{142} \leq x \leq \frac{2639}{111}$